# R: remove unit from dataframe

Tags: r

How can I remove the units from certain columns in a dataframe in R?

I have a dataframe (three rows, three columns) that looks like:

```
1 mm  apple  4 cm
11 mm  car  8 cm
22 mm  3  3 cm
```

The outcome should look like:

```
1  apple  4 
11  car  8 
22  3  3
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We loop through the columns of interest and use `sub` to remove the non-numeric substring (`\\s+\\D+`) at the end (`$`) of the string

```
DF[-2] <- lapply(DF[-2], function(x) as.numeric(sub("\\s+\\D+$", "", x)))
DF
#  v1    v2 v3
#1  1 apple  4
#2 11   car  8
#3 22     3  3
```

#### data

```
DF <- data.frame(v1 = c('1 mm', '11 mm', '22 mm'), v2 = c('apple', 
     'car', 3), v3 = c('4 cm', '8 cm', '3 cm'), stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
```